ngValue truncated to 50 characters in Angular select element
While developing a web application using Angular 15, the value from a select element using ngValue is truncated to 50 characters. When I inspect the event.target.value, it only returns the first 50 characters, even though the full value is longer than 50 characters.
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" (change)="onChange($event)">
  <option *ngFor="let item of items" [ngValue]="item.longStringValue">{{ item.displayValue }}</option>
</select>

export class MyComponent {

  selectedValue: string;

  items = [
    { longStringValue: 'a very long string that exceeds fifty characters and gets truncated', displayValue: 'Item 1' },
    // other items
  ];

  onChange(event: any) {
    console.log(event.target.value); // Logs only the first 50 characters
  }
}

Issue
When accessed via event.target.value, the value assigned to [ngValue] is truncated to 50 characters. Is there a known character limit on the ngValue binding? How can I ensure that the entire string value is retained and not truncated?

use (input) instead of (change)
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" (input)="onChange($event)">

OR split ngModel in the way
<!--see that in this case $event is the "value", not the event-->
<select [ngModel]="selectedValue" 
        (ngModelChange)="selectedValue=$event;onChange($event)">

onChange(value:string)
{
    console.log(value)(
}


This is working as intended. ngValue is a feature by Angular so the value of a select can also be an object, which is not supported by basic HTML. However when using ngValue, the value somehow needs to be converted back into a string so the native HTML element can handle it. This is done in the Angular source code, where the value is also being truncated. When using ngValue you should not rely on event.target.value.
There are two approaches to fix it:

Use value instead of ngValue. As a result the basic HTML implementation is used where no truncation is happening.

Use the ngModelChange event instead of the change event:
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)">
  <option *ngFor="let item of items" [ngValue]="item.longStringValue">{{ item.displayValue }}</option>
</select>

onChange(value: string) {
  console.log(value);
}



